# Parsing JIRA Insights API JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq, jira-rest-api

So I basically have JSON output from the JIRA Insights API, been digging around and found jq for parsing the JSON.  Struggling to wrap my head around on how parse the following to only return values for the objectTypeAttributeId's that I am interested in.

For Example I'm only interested in the value of objectTypeAttributeId 887 provided that objectTypeAttributeId 911's name states as active, but then would like to return the name value of another objectTypeAttributeId

Can this be achieved using jq only?  Or shoudl I be using something else?

I can filter down to this level which is the 'attributes' section of the JSON output and print each value, but struggling to find an example catering for my situation.

```
 {
      "id": 137127,
      "objectTypeAttributeId": 887,
      "objectAttributeValues": [
        {
          "value": "false"
        }
      ],
      "objectId": 9036,
      "position": 16
    },
    {
      "id": 137128,
      "objectTypeAttributeId": 888,
      "objectAttributeValues": [
        {
          "value": "false"
        }
      ],
      "objectId": 9036,
      "position": 17
    },
    {
      "id": 137296,
      "objectTypeAttributeId": 911,
      "objectAttributeValues": [
        {
          "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Active",
            "category": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "objectId": 9036,
      "position": 18
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be achieved using jq only?

Yes, jq was designed precisely for this kind of query. In your case, you could use `any`, `select` and `if ... then ... else ... end`, along the lines of:

```
if any(.[]; .objectTypeAttributeId == 911 and
            any(.objectAttributeValues[]; .status.name == "Active"))
then map(select(.objectTypeAttributeId == 887))
else "whatever"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes so much more sense now